# Macbook Retina recognizing replaced SSD as external despite being internal

Tags: display, hard-drive, macos, ssd, upgrade

Just bought a Retina Macbook Pro and swapped the SSD for a 1TB drive, it boots and seems to run fine, except the drive in 'about' shows as external and when I set in finder show/hide external it appears/disappears-

Is this going to be an issue (boots and runs) and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you boot your Mac from?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will only show up as internal if it's connected to the internal bus on the motherboard.  Anything else will display as external.  You can change the icons if you want it to **look** like an internal drive from Finder.